# CTE SQL deleted table b instead of table a

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I'm planning to delete table A's data within the key that I found from table B via CTE. But somehow this CTE didn't delete anything from table A but deleted my data in table B.

```
WITH tableA AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (100) 
        txn_id, customer_id 
    FROM 
        tableB
    WHERE 
        create_date < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 1500, GETDATE()), 0)
    ORDER BY
        create_date ASC
)
DELETE FROM tableA;
```

After I executed this SQL statement, SMSS said 100 rows affected.

Then I executed a `COUNT(*)` statement immediately to see how things are going. It turns out it didn't delete anything from Table A, but Table B had 100 rows of data deleted.

So I think I write the CTE wrong and need a help to correct this SQL.

Comment: Well... `TableA` is not a table, but a CTE that represents a subset of `TableB` since you defined it as such using `AS`.

Comment: hmmm, okay... it's unwise to use tricky skill to do the job

Comment: That's not quite how cte work, what you did was creating a temporary view around your tableB called tableA and deleted from it, thus deleting tableB data

Comment: If you have an actual object called `TableA`, then part of the problem is you gave your CTE is a misleading name.

Comment: Well... that CTE way was given by the ChatGPT. Maybe I shouldn't trust it that much.

Comment: You most certainly should not trust ChatGPT - there is a reason it's banned from this site. That said you shouldn't trust any answer you find on this site - you should always make sure you understand any answer provided before using it.

Answer (score 0):

Why use a CTE at all? Why not just a sub-query? Assuming `txn_id` is the common key.

```
DELETE FROM tableA
WHERE txn_id IN (
    SELECT TOP (100) txn_id
    FROM tableB
    WHERE create_date < DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 1500, GETDATE()), 0)
    ORDER BY create_date ASC
);
```

Comment: Yep, this is my previous design. then the client complain that it took too long and ask me to provide another SQL. So I asked ChatGPT and got that CTE.

Comment: CTEs don't perform any better, they are just a "cleaner" syntax. To resolve a performance issue you need to inspect the execution plan and see why it is taking too long (or post it in a new question if you don't understand it)